# Reading in .CSV individual values

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsobject

I have a .CSV File below that is already put into a nice format rather than a solid list of values.

[image]

How would i be able to read individual values from this list … for example 'Time of 5 & 6" and return the number?

I know how would retrieve this from a normal .csv file that is listed, however not from one that has a weird layout like this one. Any ideas?

Thank

Comment: Not done CSV parsing, But may this help you https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Nice from the point of view of human readable, or machine readable? Show the actual CSV / parsed content log. How far have you got? What does it do wrong?

Comment: Its in this format to be human readable, however its needs to be machine readable too as to generate a report. So far I only have ideas. This includes maybe getting values out of array index. However the layout structure may change length if there are more times. So i'm unsure as of best way.

Answer (score 0):

If the column titles (such as "Time 4" and "Time of 5 & 6") are consistent, you could separate each line and then by commas, look for the index of the column title, and then grab the same column in the next line.
I haven't tested this, but I think it should work. Assuming your file is read in as a string:

```
NSArray *componentsByLine = [myFile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

int firstIndex = 0;
int secondIndex = 0;
BOOL found = NO;

for(firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < componentsByLine.count; firstIndex++)
{
    NSArray *componentsByComma = [[componentsByLine objectAtIndex:firstIndex] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    for(secondIndex = 0; secondIndex < componentsByComma.count; secondIndex++)
    {
        if([[componentsByComma objectAtIndex:secondIndex] isEqualToString:@"Time of 5 & 6"])
        {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(found)
        break;
}

float requestedTime = [[[[componentsByLine objectAtIndex:firstIndex+1] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:secondIndex] floatValue];
```